# Position figure[p] in between sections

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I am positioning a figure between sections, hoping to have

```
page 1: sec 1
page 2: figure
page 3: sec 2
```

But this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section*{sec 1}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics{noimage}
\end{figure}

\section*{sec 2}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

gets me:

```
page 1: sec 1, sec 2
page 2: figure
```

Placing `\newpage` between `sec 1` and `figure`, I got

```
page 1: sec 1
page 2: sec 2
page 3: figure
```

How do I position `figure[p]` to have

```
page 1: sec 1
page 2: figure
page 3: sec 2
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage` (the former flushes out the floats in the stack), and it should come *after* the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section*{sec 1}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics{noimage}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\section*{sec 2}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you put `\clearpage` or `\newpage` *before* the `figure` environment, then the current page 1 is ended, the float is met and put in a stack until the routine decides where to place it, and it will be placed *after* the current page 2, so on page 3.

With `\newpage` after the `figure` environment the new page 2 is forced but the floats are not flushed out. The float is in the stack and again the algorithm will place it after the current page. Here is the difference  with `\clearpage`, which will end the current page 1 (by calling `\newpage` internally) *and* output the floats in the stack.